# How to hide a UILabel from another UIViewController using Notifications and Observer

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 `UIViewControllers` and I try to hide an `UILabel` from the second `UIViewController` using `Notifications` and `Observer`.
Is the first time when I use this design pattern and I'm a little bit confused. What I'm doing wrong ?
I want to specify that I'm getting the message from that print for the first time only when I click the back button from the second ViewController.
And after that I'm getting the message normal when I click `Go Next` but the `UILabel` is not hidden or colour changed.

Here is my code for first `UIViewController`:

```
class ReviewPhotosVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("NotificationOfReviewMode"), object: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func goNextTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let fullscreenVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FullscreenPhoto") as! FullscreenPhotoVC

        self.present(fullscreenVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Here is my code for second `UIViewController`:

```
class FullscreenPhotoVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var customLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(hideCustomLabel),
                                               name: Notification.Name("NotificationOfReviewMode"),
                                               object: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func goBackTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let reviewPhotosVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ReviewPhotos") as! ReviewPhotosVC

        self.present(reviewPhotosVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @objc func hideCustomLabel(){

        customLabel.isHidden = true
        customLabel.textColor = .red
        print("My func was executed.")
    }
}
```

Here is my Storyboard:

[image]

Thanks if you read this.

Comment: In your "go back" function you are presenting a new instance of your first view controller. You want `self.dismiss(animated)` to dismiss the second view controller and go back to the first. You also have a problem because you are posting the notification from the first view controller long before the second view controller registers to receive the notification.

Comment: If you are wanting to learn how notifications work then great, but I will point out that you don't need it in this case since your first view controller has a reference to the second, so it can just call the `hideCustomLabel` function directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are posting the notification before the next controller is initialised and has started observing. Also, there is no need for the notification you can do it directly. In this case I have used an extra variable `shouldHideLabel` as you cannot call the function `hideCustomLabel()` directly because this will lead to crash as the outlets are only initialised after view is loaded.

```
class ReviewPhotosVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("NotificationOfReviewMode"), object: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func goNextTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let fullscreenVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FullscreenPhoto") as! FullscreenPhotoVC
        fullscreenVC.shouldHideLabel = true
        self.present(fullscreenVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

class FullscreenPhotoVC: UIViewController {

    var shouldHideLabel = false

    @IBOutlet weak var customLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if shouldHideLabel {
            hideCustomLabel()
        }
        /*
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(hideCustomLabel),
                                               name: Notification.Name("NotificationOfReviewMode"),
                                               object: nil)
        */
    }

    @IBAction func goBackTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @objc func hideCustomLabel() {
        customLabel.isHidden = true
        customLabel.textColor = .red
        print("My func was executed.")
    }
}
```