# How to hide a UILabel from another/second UIViewController?

Tags: swift, uilabel, viewcontroller

[How to hide a UILabel from another UIViewController using Notifications and Observer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55727517/how-to-hide-a-uilabel-from-another-uiviewcontroller-using-notifications-and-obse)

Hi, I am looking for a similar solution as the above link, but is there a way to do it the other way around? I want to have the button on the secondVC, and change/hide the UILabel from the firstVC? Any way to achieve this?

Comment: I think the delegate pattern would make more sense in this case. Just create a delegate protocol and let the first viewController be the delegate of the second. Then you can inform it when the button is tapped.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be using `closures`.
To achieve this, you can define a `closure` in your second viewController and call it from the first one.

Here is the example:

in the second view controller define:

```swift
var hideLabel: (() -> Void)?
```

Then in your button action call it:

```swift
hideLabel?()
```

in the first view controller you can use it in this way:

```swift
secondVC.hideLabel = { [weak self] in
      // do what you need, hide your label
}
```